# Class change when mouse over

Tags: javascript

I have a function in javascript that changes a span class when I click on a button, but when I move the mouse over the that span the class changes for the old one. Why?

Comment: There has to be an event listener for some mouse event (mouseover, mouseenter) that sets the class. But without seeing any code, this is hard to debug. Do you know jsfiddle.net and jsbin.com. Would be prime if you would add a demo there (in this case, I would even say you would be figuring it out just by putting that demo together).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your html button was rendered like this:

```
<button class="btn-primary">Awesome Button</button>
<p>My class is <span class="label">btn-primary</span>
```

You might replace it's class like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger');
    $('span').text('btn-danger');
});​
```

[Here is a functional jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JsNGT/10/)

Comment: I'll show my function  <br/>

<code>function getCheck(id, ids){
    
    var table = document.getElementsByName(id+'table');
    var array = ids.split(";");
    
    for (i=1; i<table[0].rows.length; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<array.length;j++){
            var text = table[0].rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML; 
            if (text==array[j]){
                document.getElementsByName(id+'table')[0].rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].className = "ui-checkbox ui-checkbox-state-checked";
            }
        }
    }
}</code>

Comment: Are you avoiding using jQuery?